# Any alternative to Google Colab?

Tags: machine-learning, colab

I have to train vgg16 from scratch on a digit dataset as my college project. I require more computational power. Can anyone suggest to me how can I do that other than Google Colab? Currently, it is taking approx 17 hours to run one epoch? Like on cloud or anything? and it should be cost-efficient too as I'm just a student.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can give a try in JOVIAN. Even you can go with Kaggle Notebooks. Also, suggest to activate GPU Runtime in Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

I am starting to use [Notealbe](https://app.noteable.io). This is a damn nice choice.

Answer (score 0):

[Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) is a nice platform for running notebooks in the cloud. Notebooks are offered for pretty much all languages that can be run in a jupyter notebook.